# WSDL "valueofPrompt"

Tags: xml, wsdl

Cuento con un documento WSDL generado a través de SAP Business Objects.
Y desde el lenguaje PHP intento enviarle un valor constante a "valueofPrompt" (del documento WSDL). Pero no sé bien, bien como hacerlo :-(

```
<s:complexType name="LovValueIndex">
<s:sequence>
  <s:element name="valueofPrompt" type="s:string" /> 
  <s:element name="index" type="s:string" /> 
  </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
```

Por favor, ¿alguien puede decirme cómo hacerlo?

Desde PHP llamo al WSDL, concretamente al método GetReportBlock_miInforme4:

```
$params = '<GetReportBlock_miInforme4 xmlns="'.$boWSName.'"><login>'.$boUser.'</login><password>'.$boPwd.'</password><refresh>true</refresh></GetReportBlock_miInforme4>';

$result = $client->call('GetReportBlock_miInforme4',$params);
```

Gracias de antemano.

Saludos.

Comment: no sé mucho de wsdl ya que solo me he conectado a apis, no he creado ninguna pero todas a las que me he conectado que tienen esta estructura `<xsd:complexType name="DTORegion"><xsd:all><xsd:element name="codigo" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/><xsd:element name="nombre" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/><xsd:element name="nivel" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/></xsd:all></xsd:complexType>`